# How to fix a type mismatch between Manifest and ManifestFactory in Scala?

Tags: scala, debugging, manifest, scala-reflect

I'm debugging code similar to this (scala 2.11.8):

```
class Whatever extends Serializable {
  def getParams[T: Manifest]() = doSomething()
}
```

When I try to add a watch variable with `doSomething()` in IntelliJ, I get this error:

Error evaluating method : 'doSomething': Type mismatch Can't assign scala.reflect.ManifestFactory$ to scala.reflect.Manifest

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with IntelliJ debugger. Which might make sense as `Manifest` are provided during compilation. Not sure it can be used in debugger watches. I wouldn't focus much on this error.